# Chrome で自作のウェブサイトがアクセスしにくいのはセキュリティーの問題でしょうか？

Tags: apache, ssl

SSL証明書とApacheの関係性についての質問です。

MAMP を使い、自分で作成しているウェブサイトを公開しようとしているところです。スマートフォン版のウェブブラウザーを含めて殆どのブラウザーで問題なく自作ウェブサイトの表示ができていますが、パソコン版の Chrome だと、ウェブサイトが表示されたり、表示されなくなったりします。

表示されない時、ブラウザーのキャシュを削除すれば表示されます。また、家のWi-fi以外のWi-fi（カフェのWi-fiなど）から自作ウェブサイトにアクセスしようとすると、パソコン版の Chrome だけでなく、Firefox でも接続しにくくなります。

調べたところ、アクセスしづらいのはセキュリティーの問題という情報が見つかりました。これは本当でしょうか？ いずれか自分のウェブサイトのセキュリティーを強化してSSL証明書を追加しようと思いますが、そうすることで、どのブラウザーでも自分のウェブサイトへ円滑にアクセスできるようになりますか？月々料金を支払ってどこかのウェブホスティングを利用した方が最も確実な公開のし方でしょうか？

自分のウェブサイトのURLは下記の通りです
↓
https://morikoboshi.com

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 妄想と憶測で事を進めても何にもなりません。本当に「セキュリティの問題」とやらであるのかどうか確認してから方策を検討しても遅くないです。現代 Web UA はサーバ側が十分高速であることを前提に http / https 接続開始から完了までのタイムアウト時間が短くなっているので、接続できない＝あなたのサーバが遅いだけかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

まずは自身の web サーバがどのポートで待ち受けているのかを確認してください。
一般的には http(80), https(443) ですが、https は証明書の取得が必要です。

ブラウザから http(s) の入力を省略した場合、現在のブラウザは https と仮定してまずアクセスし、うまく繋がらない時は次に http での接続を試す場合があるので、ここで時間がかかるケースがあります。

上記とは別に、待ち受けているサーバ自体の処理性能や回線速度の影響で時間がかかるケースも考えられます。

該当の web サイトは http であればアクセス自体はできるようですが、表示されるまでには少し時間がかかるように感じます。

Comment: Edgeで試したところhttpsではタイムアウトし、httpでも非常に遅かったです。待てないユーザーが多いかもしれませんね。

Comment: 皆さん発言内に書かれた未知の URL を無造作にポチっとするんだ。勇気あるなあ。 / 何が遅いのかは要調査っスね。 http なのかもしれないし DNS かもしれないし省電力設定のせいかもしれないし。

Comment: 「DNS かもしれないし」、ほんとですね、問題はここにありそうですね、というかつまり問題のページというものは質問者さんのご自宅かどこかで動いているMacで動いているのですね。